# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel only on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, certificate, tls1.2

I have a peculiar problem where a c# app works on all other machines and other client machines I have tested. But does not establish a connection on my clients Windows Server 2012 hosted by his ISP. This app have been working up to about 2 days ago on this machine according to my client and uses .Net4.5.2. I have no idea what changed the last couple of days unfortunately.

**What I have tested on this machine:**

- Using Chrome the url works
- Using Edge the url works
- hitting the URL with curl works
- Using IE11 the url does **not** work
- Using our app does **not** work
- Using a quick test app does **not** work

This is the same no matter what settings I change on the server or in the app.

**Error from my app:**

```
AuthResponse is null: False 
AuthResponse ErrorException: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at RestSharp.Http.WriteRequestBody(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
   at RestSharp.Http.PostPutInternal(String method)
   at RestSharp.Http.AsPost(String httpMethod)
   at RestSharp.RestClient.DoExecuteAsPost(IHttp http, String method)
   at RestSharp.RestClient.Execute(IRestRequest request, String httpMethod, Func`3 getResponse)
AuthResponse ErrorMessage: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

**Error from IE11:**

```
Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to  again. If this error persists, it is possible that this site uses an unsupported protocol or cipher suite such as RC4 (link for the details), which is not considered secure. Please contact your site administrator.
```

**Errors From Event Viewer:**

```
A fatal alert was received from the remote endpoint. The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 40.
A fatal alert was generated and sent to the remote endpoint. This may result in termination of the connection. The TLS protocol defined fatal error code is 40. The Windows SChannel error state is 1205.
A fatal error occurred while creating an SSL client credential. The internal error state is 10013.
```

There are a lot of these errors in event viewer, I just copied three of them in case they are actually relevant.

**What I have tried:**

I used [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) to change and configure all manner of settings and testing in between. All with the same results. I have modified my app with quite a few changes I have found by searching all with the same results as well. Some of the code changes I made below:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

This is not all the changes I tried. I tried all kinds of different variations as well such as only tls1.2. I have used my little test app as well to connect to other https sites like google and my other rest service and no error is reported on this machine.

Our Auth server uses Lets Encrypts certificates and uses OAth and only accepts tls2.1. I have hit another REST Api that we use that also use Lets Encrypt and that is working. I don't know if I need to update the certificate store (if that is possible), or if there is a setting I'm missing. I'm honestly at a loss here.

**Test app source if that helps at all:**

```
static async Task test(string url)
{
    // Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions.
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        MessageBox.Show(result.StatusCode.ToString());
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 40 is a handshake failure, error state 1205 identifies the cause in a cipher suites exchange failure (in the handshake, the endpoint and the client could not find a common available/accepted cipher). The endpoint may have determined that the client can only understand SHA1, while SHA256 is expected. SHA may have been disabled by a security update or someone did. `IIS Crypto` should give you the information. You can try to install .Net Framework 4.8 (which brings in TLS1.3).

Comment: See [TLS Handshake Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-handshake-protocol) and [Secure Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/secure-channel).

Comment: @TJ Snyman How did you solved the problem? We have the same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had the same problem today.
Some unsafe cipher suites were removed at our webserver yesterday.
Though vulnerable, adding these cipher suites fixed the problem.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/manage-tls

Here is list of cipher suites:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2929781/update-adds-new-tls-cipher-suites-and-changes-cipher-suite-priorities

Listing supported cipher suites:
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/win32/secauthn/prioritizing-schannel-cipher-suites?redirectedfrom=MSDN#listing-supported-cipher-suites

Comment: Dutch page explaining how to change the order of the cipher suites: https://www.sslcertificaten.nl/support/IIS_FAQ/IIS_-_Instellen_TLSv1.2

Comment: This page is also useful to read:
https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto

Comment: Thanks Chris, the links solved my issue. In the mean time I told the client to migrate to a newer version of windows server as a more permanent "fix".

Comment: The update 2919355 is installed on our machine but we still get the same error as TJ Snyman explained, our environment and usage exactly the same as his.

Answer (score 4):

I also have the same issue like this, after searching for a while, there's a few things you need to do:

1. First you check the url you need to access/query, which type "Connection Encrypted" that Url uses? The easy way is open the url via Mozila or Chrome then check the "Connection Encrypted"
   [this example for my case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDNDg.png)
2. Then try search available TLS cipher that's available for Windows Server 2012 at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-8-1. Find the "Connection Encrypted" from first step, for this step no.2, if you can't find it "Cipher suite string", so it means your server can't call that url via C# code.

Even if you set this in your code.
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` 
Because Windows Server 2012 can't support that "Connection Encrypted"

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 3):

You have probably resolved the issue, but I just came across this same issue where an external api call failed due to the same error of "Could not create SSL/TLS Secure Channel".

I spent two days on it and the fix was first checking what TLS version and cipher is supported on the endpoint by using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

After that, I used IIS Crypto to enable the proper ciphers accordingly, rearrange the ciphers in the order provided by SSLLabs and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone.

I just had this very problem with Windows Server 2019 Datacenter.

The X.509 certificate I was using to secure my self-hosted service on the server was old and weak, RSA 1024, MD5 hash.

Event Viewer was no help in tracking down the cause.

On a hunch, I replaced the old X.509 with a newer X.509, RSA 4096, SHA256 and the error went away.

[image]