# windows server 2012 R2 : could not establish secure channel for ssl/tls

Tags: c#, .net, http, https, httpwebrequest

I Can't send https request by c# I tried to use all answers I found but I am got the same error
(could not establish secure channel for ssl/tls )
I added this line of code and it doesn't solve the problem

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3|SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

but the request work correctly when I use windows 10 but in windows 7 not working although it work in windows 7 if I send request by Fiddler or Postman

Comment: Does this help? [Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel only on Windows Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59975964/could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-only-on-windows-server-2012)

Comment: And have you tried to enable TLS 1.2 [according to the documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392)? See also https://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/windows/305-enable-tls-1-2-on-windows-2012-r2.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.HasFlag(SecurityProtocolType.Tls12) == false)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
}
```

Comment: i got the same error