# Unable to connect to third-party API from Visual Studio, but it works in Postman

Tags: c#, api, tls1.2, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to connect to a third-party API using Visual Studio, but I'm facing an error. However, when I try to connect to the same API using Postman on the same Windows Server 2012 R2, it works fine. I've checked my code multiple times, and it seems to be correct.

Here's the code I'm using to make the API request:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
delegate (
object sender2, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
});
                     
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

var request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);


request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
                     

string username = "abc";
string password = "xyz";
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
byte[] byte1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XML);
request.ContentLength = byte1.Length;
request.Timeout = 60 * 1000;


Stream poststream = request.GetRequestStream();
poststream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
poststream.Close();
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
var msg = sr.ReadToEnd();
response.Close();

return "(" + response.StatusCode + ")" + msg;
```

And here's the error message I'm getting:
`The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`

P.S. Same code is working at local machine.

I'm not sure what the issue is, and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

1. Tried using postman generated code
2. Tried updating Ciphers (as per my knowladge)
3. Tried changing registry settings

Comment: Have you confirmed the SSL/TLS versions supported by the server? Given that anything less than TLS 1.2 is no longer considered secure, did you try with TLS 1.3? (Is that even supported on Window 2012 R2?!)

Comment: Did you see this similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/59975964/592958

Comment: @phuzi - yes, I checked and enabled 1.3 but still throws the same error.

Comment: This is fixed, it was happening due to the old OS version (2012 R2), and as I upgraded to 2016, the same code started working.